# how is the code for uploading the parsed data to the tableview?

Tags: iphone

hi all Through below code i am getting full data but here i have to store total data into NSMtablearray object. how it is possible in iphone

```
for (int i=0; i<[arrStation count]; i++) {
    NSLog(@"--->>>ContactNameis:<<<---- %@",[[[[[arrStation objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"content"] objectForKey:@"m:properties"] objectForKey:@"d:ContactName"] objectForKey:@"text"]);
```

Below the Log printed.

2012-02-29 11:32:32.652 ContactTesting[883:f803] --->>>ContactNameis:<<<---- 
        Enrico Gaetani
2012-02-29 11:32:32.655 ContactTesting[883:f803] --->>>ContactNameis:<<<---- 
        Jérôme Tredan
2012-02-29 11:32:32.656 ContactTesting[883:f803] --->>>ContactNameis:<<<---- 
        Mike Tsalidis
2012-02-29 11:32:32.657 ContactTesting[883:f803] --->>>ContactNameis:<<<---- 
        Dana Sugarman
2012-02-29 11:32:32.659 ContactTesting[883:f803] --->>>ContactNameis:<<<---- 
        Necip Ozyucel
2012-02-29 11:32:32.660 ContactTesting[883:f803] --->>>ContactNameis:<<<---- 
        Goksel Topbas
2012-02-29 11:32:32.661 ContactTesting[883:f803] --->>>ContactNameis:<<<---- 
        Nizar Abdul-Baki
2012-02-29 11:32:32.662 ContactTesting[883:f803] --->>>ContactNameis:<<<---- 
        Johannes Kanis
2012-02-29 11:32:32.664 ContactTesting[883:f803] --->>>ContactNameis:<<<---- 
        Kara Westhusing
2012-02-29 11:32:32.665 ContactTesting[883:f803] --->>>ContactNameis:<<<---- 
        Andreas Erlacher
2012-02-29 11:32:32.668 ContactTesting[883:f803] --->>>ContactNameis:<<<---- 
        Rudy Van Hoe
2012-02-29 11:32:32.669 ContactTesting[883:f803] --->>>ContactNameis:<<<---- 
        Lars Nygaard
2012-02-29 11:32:33.104 ContactTesting[883:f803] --->>>ContactNameis:<<<---- 
        Juha Karppinen
2012-02-29 11:32:33.132 ContactTesting[883:f803] --->>>ContactNameis:<<<---- 
        Ronan Geraghty
2012-02-29 11:32:33.134 ContactTe

Comment: you want only last data that is printed in `NSLog` or you want to covert all the data into `NSMutableArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should Store These parsed data into Array.

Create Array and Add names in that Array

```
NSMutableArray *myArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i=0; i<[arrStation count]; i++){
NSString *str=[[[[[arrStation objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"content"]   objectForKey:@"m:properties"] objectForKey:@"d:ContactName"] objectForKey:@"text"];
NSlog("name is : %@",str);
[myArray addObject:str];
```

}

After Storing the Data into Array follow below Link at Where I have Explained everything about showing data In TableView

[Go through this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493280/what-is-code-for-upload-the-nsmutablearray-data-to-tableview/9494103#9494103)

It'll Really Helpful.