# UITableViewCell.contentView error after turning on ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm fairly new to IOS development, so I apologise if this is an ignorant question.

After refactoring my code to use ARC, I've started getting a SIGABRT error which is thrown when the following line is executed:

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:labelTag];
```

The console output includes the following:

**'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM contentView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1acba0'**

The context of that line is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    const NSInteger labelTag = 1;
    const NSInteger textFieldTag = 2;

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    if([indexPath section] == 0) {
        if([indexPath row] == 0) {
            //this is the username row. Set the label accordingly.

            cell = [[TextFieldCellController alloc] init];

            UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:labelTag];
            label.text = @"Username";
        }
        else if([indexPath row] == 1) {
            //this is the row that contains the password input. Set the label and
            //change the textfield to use a password input style.

            cell = [[TextFieldCellController alloc] init];

            UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:labelTag];
            label.text = @"Password";

            UITextField *text = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:textFieldTag];
            text.secureTextEntry = YES;


        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

I was playing around in the console window and when I typed "print cell.contentView" after putting a breakpoint on that line, I got "There is no member named contentView.". I'm not sure if that's helpful.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit:

Sorry, TextFieldCellController is a subclass of UITableViewCell that loads a nib containing a label and text field.

```
@implementation TextFieldCellController

@synthesize label;
@synthesize textField;

- (id)init {
    self = (TextFieldCellController *)[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TextFieldCell" owner:self options:nil];
    return self;
}
```

Comment: The message is telling you that `cell` points to an object of class `__NSArrayM`, which is a private implementation of the `NSArray` interface.  So show us the `-[TextFieldCellController init]` method.

Comment: TextFieldCellController what is this ..?,and you are not creating cells properly.see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494281/how-is-the-code-for-uploading-the-parsed-data-to-the-tableview/9494402#9494402.

Comment: I've updated the initial question to describe the subclass.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't how to implement `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Why aren't you calling `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`?

Also (and probably more important) you cannot create a table view cell by calling `alloc init` like that. The designated initializer is `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`; I believe you *must* call it.

Finally, I'm very suspicious of this TextFieldCellController. If it is a UITableViewCell subclass then initializing it like this isn't going to cause it to have any subview with a tag of 1 or 2. If it is not a UITableViewCell subclass then what on earth is it? I hope you're not using a UIViewController to load a cell from a nib; that would be terribly wrong.

Comment: I thought dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier was optional? I spent a while trying to figure out how to have a reusable custom cell. This was working until I enabled ARC. Can you tell me a better way? I've updated the initial question.