# UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath / Assertion failure messages

Tags: uitableview

Implemented UITableView with custom UITableViewCell with below code

```
    @interface ProfileSaveViewController : UITableViewController
     {
         UITableViewCell *cell0;
         UITableViewCell *cell1;
         UITableViewCell *cell2;
         UILabel *cell2Label;
     }

    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cell0;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cell1;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cell2;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *cell2Label;

    @end

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:               (NSIndexPath*)indexPath
  {
        if([indexPath row] == 0) return cell0;
        if([indexPath row] == 1) return cell1;
        if([indexPath row] == 2) return cell2;   
        return nil;
  }
```

follwing message came when running the application.

*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1912.3/UITableView.m:6072
2012-03-01 11:11:31.984 TestSplitView[765:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're being asked for a cell and returning `nil` (or maybe something else that's not a `UITableViewCell`).  It's just that simple.

I see two possibilities:

- You are returning a number larger than 3 from `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`.  Don't.
- One or more of your `cell#` outlets is not hooked up in your nib, or is not hooked up to a `UITableViewCell` (or subclass).  Hook them up properly.

Comment: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return 3;
}

Comment: Then it's the other possibility.  You haven't hooked all of your outlets up to table view cells.

Comment: Did you mean "hooked up" by set referencing outlet atrribute?

Comment: Yes.  In the nib, you need to connect the `cell1`, `cell2`, and `cell3` outlets of the table view controller to three separate instances of `UITableViewCell`.

Answer (score 4):

In case you're using a custom UITableViewCell, is also possible that you forgot to identify "Identifier" on "Utilites side" -> "Attribute Inspector" tab.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is Not a way to creating the TableView.
You just need to study the UITableView Class Documentation.

[YOu may also go through this Link at where i Explained correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493280/what-is-code-for-upload-the-nsmutablearray-data-to-tableview/9494103#9494103)

[This is For UITAbleView Documentation , here you will get rich Explanation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: It's totally fine to create a static set of table view cells if you have a small number of cells.

Comment: In fact the technique is described in the *[Table View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW32)* under the heading “The Technique for Static Row Content”.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Dynamic Prototype cell in UITableView */

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView ==tblUser) {
        switch (indexPath.row)
        {
            case 0:
                return Cell_0;
                break;
            case 1:
                return Cell_1;
                break;
            case 2:
                return Cell_2;
                break;
            case 3:
                return Cell_3;
                break;
            case 4:
                return Cell_4;
                break;
            case 5:
                return Cell_04;
                break;
            case 6:
                return Cell_5;
                break;
            case 7:
                return Cell_6;
                break;
            case 8:
                return Cell_7;
                break;
            default:
                return nil;
                break;
        }
    }else
return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your should check your tableview datasource method for number of rows. Make sure that

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   return 3;
}
```

If you are returning more than that, then your cellForRow would return nil, which tableview datasource expects UITableViewCell instance, due to that assertion fails.