# Loading Data into Table View Controller

Tags: iphone

Can anyone point me towards any good tutorials for loading data into a Table View Controller? I want to have a table view full of exercises that is separated by body part. Once clicked on, this will take you to a description of the exercise. Please let me know if you know any good ones.

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493280/what-is-code-for-upload-the-nsmutablearray-data-to-tableview/9494103#9494103

Answer (score 0):

Here is one tutorial: http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/10/uitableview-tutorial/ explaining how Table Views are put together.

Here is a video tutorial about building a tasks application: http://www.iosconsultancy.co.uk/tag/tasks4part/.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.bogotobogo.com/XcodeSDK-Chapter7.html

This tutorial will be helpful to you.